# Whenever crontab -- undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, nomethoderror, whenever

I'm using whenever to set up a mailer but I'm getting the following error in my `cron` log:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval': undefined method `unreadmailer' for #<Class:0x00000101b7a5c8> (NoMethodError)
```

I call my method in the schedule.rb as follows:

```
every 5.minutes do 
    runner "Message.unreadmailer"
end
```

and in my `message.rb` model class I have the method defined as follows:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.unreadmailer
   @message = Message.all
   @message.each do |m|
      if m.receiver == 0 && m.readStatus == 0
       messageMailer.message_email(m.belongs_to).deliver
   end
  end 
end
```

why is it an undefined method?

my mailer is defined as follows (I don't think it has to do with the mailer because the website has a mailer not linked with whenever that works)

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 ADMIN = 'xxxx@xx.edu'

  def message_email(patient)
   @patient = patient
   mail(to: ADMIN, subject: 'New message at xxxxx.xxx.edu')
  end
 end
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with your function definition in ActionMailer? I could write an answer, but I've not got super experience with the `whenever` gem

Comment: Can you share your whole Message model?